# How to get an ajax event to fire from within a p:dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

So I have been stumped most of the day today trying to call a method in my backing bean when a component changes values.  Everything works correctly if my components are outside of a `<p:dialog>`, however when nested inside a dialog the server side never happens.  Originally I was working with the `<p:calendar>` control, but noticed it also didn't work with a simple inputText.  The following example works:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Start"/>
    <p:inputText id="startOfRange" value="#{myBean.startRange}" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.startChanged}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="play"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="play" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="#{myBean.startRange}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

My backing bean method looks like

```
public void startChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) { }
```

This method is invoked after a tab out of the inputText, however when wrapped like the following the method never gets invoked:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="efDlg" zindex="10" appendToBody="true" header="Create Custom Date Range"
      modal="true" height="375" width="450" resizable="false" closable="false" >
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:outputText value="Start"/>
    <p:inputText id="startOfRange" value="#{myBean.startRange}" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.startChanged}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="play"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="play" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="#{myBean.startRange}"/>
    <p:inputText id="endOfRange" value="#{myBean.endRange}" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.endChanged}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<div class="customRangeButtons">
    <span>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onstart="efDlg.hide();" actionListener="#{myBean.cancelCustomDateRange}" update="pGraphs"/>
    </span>
    <span style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <p:commandButton  value="Ok" type="submit" onstart="efDlg.hide();" action="#{myBean.saveCustomDateRange()}" update="pGraphs"/>
    </span>
</div>    
</p:dialog>
```

Note I am using Primefaces 2.2.1 with Mojarra 2.1.0.  Any ideas as to why I can't get the startChanged method to be called when the value has changed?

Comment: As a work around I switched out the p:dialog and manually crafted a jQuery dialog.  That is working well.

Comment: This is a sensible alternative.  Even with 2.2.1 being the stable release, it has a far way to come with the dialog component.  These are common and recurring themes where certain component behaviors are different or non-existant when contained within the dialog.  From what I gather it mostly has to do with the way the underlying YUI dialog physically moves DOM elements into and out of the form.

Comment: I've been having major problems with `<p:dialog>`. I think it doesn't play well with a Facelet page that also uses `<p:layout>`. Not sure if you're using a layout also. I'm hoping that they will stabilize the dialog in future releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong about this (I don't have my project code at home to verify) but isn't this:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="play"/>
```

supposed to be:

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" update="play"/>
```

I know that most of the Ajax `event` values are like the JavaScript event handlers with the 'on' removed, but `valueChange` is a special value in JSF Ajax tags.

For the record, I sometimes pair up two Ajax child tags inside an inputText, like:

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" update="whatever"/>
<p:ajax event="keyUp" process="@this" update="whatever"/>
```

This will deal with each keystroke at it is entered as well as copy-and-paste and loss of focus on the parent input text.

Comment: The `event="valueChange"` has indeed a special meaning. It will render as `onchange` of HTML textboxes, textareas and dropdowns and as `onclick` of HTML radiobuttons and checkboxes. However, in this particular case, `event="change"` has exactly the same effect as it's been used in a textbox. The root cause is probably that `<p:dialog>` actually needs its own `<h:form>` (which should not be nested!). At least, RichFaces has a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on `valueChange`. I think you're probably right about the dialog and form. The PrimeFaces showcase examples tend to have the dialog in its own form. Also, I see the OP is using the `appendToBody="true"` attribute. This seems to be some kind of workaround for an issue they are having. I have to use it in my webapp if my page template uses the `<p:layout>`, otherwise the dialog will not render properly. Maybe it's related? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across the same problem. I am also using a single form and no form inside the dialog. As long as I do not have the appendToBody="true" for my dialog the input values and ajax and submit happens correctly. As soon as I add that attribute with true, for better/correct rendering, the input values are not accepted.